# AngularJS $http issue

Tags: json, angularjs, http, post, get

i'm pretty new to AngularJS and i have a little problem.

I receive JSON data from an api, I display all the data with ng-repeat.

Then from each different object, when I click on Id link for exemple, i would like to display in another page only the specific data for this object. I don't have any problem with the route, I go fine to the page, but when i try form exemple to display the "Name", i get this : {{name}}

Here go my two controllers :

```
    var toulouseVeloControllers = angular.module('toulouseVeloControllers', []);

toulouseVeloControllers.controller('toulouseVeloListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=toulouse&apiKey=************************').success(function(data) {
      $scope.bornes = data;
    });
  }]);

    toulouseVeloControllers.controller('toulouseVeloDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
      function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations/' + data.number + '?contract=Toulouse&apiKey=*******************************').success(function(data) {

      $scope.name = data;
    });
  }]);
```

Does someone can help ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Can you make a plunker? It helps us to help you.

Comment: post your problematic code also not only working code

Comment: @Hiru He could not address the problematic code bro, that why he asked.

Comment: Always watch at the javascript console, it could save you a lot of time. The mistake @Rikky found should actually be displayed in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 toulouseVeloControllers.controller('toulouseVeloDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {....
```

This one is the problem, you have not injected enough dependencies in to the controller. Fixing it by add the $routeParams dependency to the controller. Like this:

```
 toulouseVeloControllers.controller('toulouseVeloDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {....
```